# How to describe an algorithm to decide whether T is a depth-first spanning tree rooted at s?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, depth-first-search

Let's Suppose we have a connected graph G, a start vertex s, and a spanning tree T of G and G is undirected. How can I describe an algorithm to decide if T is a depth-first spanning tree rooted at s or not?

Answer (score 2):

All DFS trees T for an undirected graph G have the following property:

> {u, v} is an edge in G if and only if u is an ancestor of v in T or v is an ancestor of u in T.

To see why, assume without loss of generality that u is visited before v in the DFS. When building the DFS tree node for u, we will either (1) choose to visit node v as a neighbor of u, making node u a parent of node v, or (2) starting at node u we will visit some other neighbor z, and in recursively exploring z we will visit v, in which case u is a parent of z and z is an ancestor of v.

Moreover, we can make a stronger claim: any tree meeting the above criterion is a DFS tree for some DFS tree of G. Here’s how to see this. Start with the root node of T and look at its children. Given any two subtrees of the root, none of the nodes in those subtrees can be adjacent to one another in G, since otherwise by the above property one of those nodes would have to be an ancestor of the other. Therefore, each subtree consists of a set of nodes that are all reachable from one another via paths that only involve the nodes within that subtree. We can then recursively assemble one possible DFS ordering by starting at the root, recursively building DFS trees for the subgraphs represented by the subtrees in any order we’d like, and gluing those DFS orders together.

With this observation in mind, we can check very quickly with a second DFS whether T can be a DFS tree rooted at s, tracking which nodes have been visited as the DFS runs. After all children of a node v have been processed, check whether all the neighbors of v in graph G have been visited. If so, great! If not, it means that some neighbor of v is neither an ancestor nor a descendant, and the tree isn’t a DFS tree. If this process terminated without finding any violations, the process itself traces out a DFS of G using the edges of T, so T is definitely a valid DFS tree.

This algorithm runs in time O(m + n), which is as fast as possible here. After all, if you don’t look at all the nodes or edges of G, you can’t be sure whether the tree is a valid DFS tree because you can’t check the core property listed above.